# is Cyberfox available for Ubuntu?

Tags: browser

OK! I am disappointed with Windows 10 and wondered if Ubuntu could be a better option:

1. Can I use Cyberfox Browser?
2. If I have to use the FireFox browser instead, will firefox add-ons/extensions  work just as well in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Although there isn't an official Cyberfox Linux version on their website, the portable Cyberfox version for Windows can be installed in `Wine`.

To do that:

1. Download the installer (for me it was `CyberfoxPortable_41.0.1.0_English.Amd.paf.exe`).
2. Move that installer to the directory where you want the file installed (In the screen shot below you can see I installed mine in `/media/sf_15.04drive). 3. Run the installation in the terminal; E.G.`wine CyberfoxPortable_41.0.1.0_English.Amd.paf.exe`

The above will create a Cyberfox directory with `CyberfoxPortable.exe` in it.

Now, every time you want to run Cyberfox, just call `wine /path/to/CyberfoxPortable.exe`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ubuntu.
Unfortunately Cyberfox is not available on Ubuntu and Cyberfox's developers does not have plan to create a Linux (Ubuntu) compatible version (see [here](https://8pecxstudios.com/Forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=657)).

If you want to use Firefox, all addons/extensions will work the exact same way as under Windows.

Comment: many thanks for your answer,which I thought would be the case.
as long as Firefox runs better on ubuntu than in windows I will be happy
especially as I can use all my firefox addons thats the deal breaker for me ~Please may i ask a supplementary question_
can i just download ubuntu it would be easier for me. and if I can just simply download, can i run it side by side with windows for a day or two many thanks Steve

Comment: Yes you can run it side by side with Windows, it called dual boot and it is the best solution for you. There is plenty a tutorial on internet ([here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)) for example. Moreover if my answer helped you, do not hesitate to click the `^` button and  the check mark beside my answer (see [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) for more informations) :)

Comment: @StevenSylvester You can try Ubuntu in live mode without installing, directly booting from the DVD or USB device. If you like it, you can install it as dual-boot with Windows, so that you can use both systems. And if you *really love* Ubuntu, you can later entirely replace Windows with it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

From cyberfox 33 they started creating linux builds though not in an official capacity more information [here](https://8pecxstudios.com/Forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=685)

They only have 2 versions in tar no .dep or other install able packages ether they don't know how to make one or just not until officially supporting it.